# near "COLUMN_NAME": syntax error (code 1) in SQLite

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm Working on Android project and I'm using ***SQLite*** database in that, I have written one insert query as :

```
sqliteDB_Obj.execSQL("INSERT INTO tbl_order_master (user_id, order, amount)" + "VALUES(" + strUserId +","+ strOrderString +","+ dblAmount +");");
```

But I'm getting following error

***android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "order": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tbl_order_master (user_id, order, amount) VALUES(dny, my test order, 160.0);***

some people have asked same question before so according to the answer mentioned their I have tried following way :

```
String strTableName="tbl_order_master";
String strQuery= String.format("INSERT INTO %s (user_id, order, amount) VALUES(%s, %s, %s);", strTableName, strUserId, strOrderString, ""+dblAmount);
sqliteDB_Obj.execSQL(strQuery);
```

**but still getting same error**  Please help.. Thanks..!

Comment: probably the problem is that the order name is a reserved word? try using sort_order or similar as column name or write it with backticks.

Comment: [Sqlite keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) and "order" is one of them

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: change the column name "order" or using `order`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a reserved name such as `order` as an identifier, put it in `"double quotes"`. Or just rename the identifier so it isn't a reserved keyword.

Also in SQL, string literals need to be written in `'single quotes'`. Yours are not quoted.

It's better to use parameters instead though, e.g.

```
execSQL("INSERT INTO tbl_order_master (\"user_id\", \"order\", \"amount\") VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    new String[] { strUserId, strOrderString, Double.toString(dblAmount) } );
```

passing the parameter values in the second arg.

Comment: This was a life saver. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 sqliteDB_Obj.execSQL("INSERT INTO tbl_order_master (`user_id`, `order`, `amount`)" + "VALUES('" + strUserId +"','"+ strOrderString +"',"+ dblAmount +");");
```

change the column name "order" or using **`order`**

Answer (score 0):

ORDER is reserved word in SQL so you can not use as field name

```
sqliteDB_Obj.execSQL("INSERT INTO tbl_order_master (user_id, order, amount)" + "VALUES(" + strUserId +","+ strOrderString +","+ dblAmount +");");
```

change to

```
sqliteDB_Obj.execSQL("INSERT INTO tbl_order_master (user_id, s_order, amount)" + "VALUES(" + strUserId +","+ strOrderString +","+ dblAmount +");");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of your `order` column to something else. `order` is a reserved word in `sqlite` (i.e. order by).And Also **single quotes** are missing

So try this (Change `order` like `m_order`)

```
sqliteDB_Obj.execSQL("INSERT INTO tbl_order_master (user_id, m_order, amount)" + "VALUES('" + strUserId +"','"+ strOrderString +"','"+ dblAmount +"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. As a good practice, always use quotes to wrap string field values.

```
sqliteDB_Obj.execSQL("INSERT INTO tbl_order_master (user_id, order, amount) " + " VALUES ( '"    + strUserId +"', '"+ strOrderString +"',"+ dblAmount +") ");
```